# How do batteries in parallel work?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits, electrical-resistance, voltage, batteries

So I understand that the voltage is the amount of work done per column of charge, so its sort of a "pushing force" and amp are just the charges per second, or "amount of stuff per second ", like water in a hose pipe, fir the sake of simplicity, and so if you put cells these cells in the example in parallel, the current in each cell halves and then adds up to the original current at the resistors and voltage stage the same, why does it do this?

[image: before]

[image: after]